# Write Excel Addin with VBA and then Put a button that trigger it

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, ribbon

I have written a simple excel add-in with VBA, it contains a form and related codes. after saving it as add-in and then installing it in Excel, nothing happened!

I need to put a button somewhere in ribbons that trigger my add-in, you know like "Solver".
I really need it, pleas tell me how.

I really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I think this will be helpful: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm

Answer (score 15):

Try this, needs to be added to your add-in, either in a module or in ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Const Button as String = "SomeName"

Sub Auto_Open   'Or Private Sub Workboo_Open() in ThisWorkbook
Dim CmdBar as CommandBar
Dim CmdBarMenu as CommandBarControl
Dim CmdBarMenuItem as CommandBarControl

Set CmdBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
Set CmdBarMenu = CmdBar.Controls("Tools")   ' Index 6

On Error Resume Next
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   CmdBarMenu.Controls(Button).Delete 'Just in case a button with same name already exists
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

Set CmdBarMenuItem = CmdBarMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With CmdBarMenuItem
     .Caption = Button
     .OnAction = "MainSub"    'Name of the sub it will call when button is pushed
End With

End Sub
```

Make sure you delete the button on closing Excel, otherwise an additional one will be added everytime you open your addin.

```
Sub Auto_Close 'Or Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) in ThisWorkbook
Dim CmdBar as CommandBar
Dim CmdBarMenu as CommandBarControl

Set CmdBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
Set CmdBarMenu = CmdBar.Controls("Tools")   ' Index 6

On Error Resume Next
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   CmdBarMenu.Controls(Button).Delete
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Your sub that you have created that you wish to run from button.

```
Public Sub MainSub
MsgBox("Hello")
End Sub
```

You can also add a list box in the Add-in ribbon to hold multiple buttons. First create a MenuItem as type:=msoControlPopup then within the popup add buttons as above.

As well as this VBA code, it is much easier for you to go File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon and add a new tab with a new group and assign a macro to that group. But that will only work for you, the above code will allow anyone to install the addin and have a button automate upon opening.

Hope this answers your question.