# How to automatically add a button to a ribbon in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, ribbon

Is it possible to automatically add a button to Excel Ribbon to run a macro when a user open an Excel file. Problem is I have developed a macro and would like to share it with my group members. Now on my personal computer I could customize the ribbon and assign a given button to my macro but this ribbon customization will only be available for me. So after I send out the workbook to members of my group, they will not see the button that I have assigned for the macro. I could add an ActiveX control but this will be on the sheet itself and not on the ribbon (Excel 2010)

Is there a way to do this, without having each member customize his/her ribbon.

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible but requires a mix of VBA and XML coding. You could get started by looking at this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767705(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: There are also lots of questions on stackoverflow about customizing the ribbon, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13125751/1490783) or [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ribbon+excel).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are talking about VSTO, which is the add-ins framework of MS Office, and normally, you need the VS Studio, not Express, to develop your add-ins application.

And at first, you can go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410115%28v=office.12%29.aspx to read the simple guide about the Ribbon button integration, and about other integration way and method, you can read the MSDN directly.

And of course, as a professional VSTO developer, if need, I can help you too. :)