# Excel Add-In Not Showing in Ribbon

Tags: excel, add-in, vba

I created an Excel Add-in but it won't display under the Add-in tabs. Things I've tried....

- Excel Options > Add-ins > Excel Add-Ins > Go .... Select the add-in.
- Excel Options > Add-ins > Disabled Items > Go ... I made sure it wasn't
  disabled.
- Right click the XLAM file > Properties > General Tab >
  Select Unblock....(This actually wasn't even an option for me. The UNBLOCK check box did not appear on the window).
- Excel Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Locations > Add the directory where I store my add-ins
- Excel Options > Trust Center> Addins ..... I made sure that "Require Application Addins to be signed by Trusted Publisher" was unticked

Also, this is my first ADD-IN, so if there is some code I'm supposed to include in my script, please let me know. I thought just saving it as an XLAM file would do the trick.

Comment: Have you tried closing and opening Excel after saving the add-in? I'm also not sure where you were expecting to see it in the Ribbon....?

Comment: @Mistella Yes I have.

Comment: I have done some programming with Add-in's before, and the only place I see them in the tab's is under `Developer` -> `Excel Add-ins` -> checkbox options. This lets you select if the add-in should be loaded or not. If you are expecting to see additional ribbon controls that weren't in the tab when the add-in wasn't loaded, what coding did you do to add the expected tabs?

Comment: I think Developer -> Excel Add-ins -> Checkbox options brings you to the same check box list as Excel Options > Add-ins > Excel Add-Ins > Go, so I'm pretty sure I covered that step, but my thinking was that if a file is Enabled via the check box list we both referenced, then it should automatically appear under the tab called ADD-INS. I didn't enter any code into my script to make it appear there. I thought it would be automatic. Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: By tab, I was assuming you meant the group of labels, "File" through "Help". My version of Excel (2016) does not have an "ADD-INS" tab as such. By ADD-INS tab, do you mean the ADD-INS group on the Developer tab? Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: By Tab I was referring to the sections of the Ribbon. File Home Insert Data etc. I have two laptops with Excel  2013 and Excel 2016. I don't think ADD-INS was there automatically. I went to File > Options > Customize Ribbon > and selected the  Add-Ins Tab to make it visible.

Comment: From what I've been reading, it sounds like the add-in would only show on the tab **if** the add-in uses the command bars _and_ does not create it's own tab. I cannot get my Excel to show the "ADD-INS" tab, so I'm not sure how much more help I can be.

Comment: I came here to this question due to a similar problem that I've encountered and for me, the solution was to unblock the file in Windows 10 and then it loaded on startup. Just leaving it here in case someone else encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I need to tell Excel to create a link in the ribbon upon opening the Excel application.

This thread answers my question. Sorry for the dupe.

[Write Excel Addin with VBA and then Put a button that trigger it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992205/write-excel-addin-with-vba-and-then-put-a-button-that-trigger-it)