# Excel macro from Add-in not visible

Tags: excel, vba

I created some Excel macros with VBA, saved it as .xlam file.  I copied the file to another computer (running Excel2013) and put it in the following folder:

`%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns`

I enabled the Add-In from Excel > File > Options > Add-ins.  Now I want to add those macros to Quick Access Toolbar(QAT).  In the QAT options, I choose "Macros" from drop-down menu.  The macros didn't show up as I had expected.  The list is blank.

My subs do not have parameters if that matters.  I have searched the forum and Google with no luck.  What else I can check?  Thank you!

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with one of my own add-ins. All the subs in a general module were visible; however, none of the functions were. *(Even the functions with no parameters -- tested by changing `Sub` to `Function` temporarily. The switch resulted in that macro disappearing from the macro list.)*

Since you don't mention **if** there was this issue on the first computer; I am assuming that you would see the same thing there, if you checked.

If you sometimes need a return value from those macros, could you create "calling" macros? Subs which call those functions? If you never need a return value, I would recommend just changing the designation from `Function` to `Sub` on the relevant macros.

You could also check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11182695/9259306) on how to add a button to the excel ribbon via add-in code. This could be useful if you plan on moving the add-in between multiple computers.

Comment: Thank you for your info.  I only have Subs in the module.  Those Subs don't need to return anything.  I was wondering if this has to do with security settings in Excel or what.  Sorry, this is my first time doing this.

Comment: @Helloguys Have you checked the security settings? They're in the trust center. Also, have you double-checked that the folder location is a trusted location?

Answer (score 0):

Foolish me!

I saved the macro module into personal.xlsb.  However, I was trying to export it by creating a blank spreadsheet (e.g. "Book1.xlsx") and save it as Excel Add-In (e.g. "Book1.xlam").  Of course the Book1.xlam won't contain any macro!

I apologize for newbie mistake.